# CosmicMind/Graph - Search query with 3 parameters is not returning expected entity

Tags: graph, swift3, cosmicmind

i am having some trouble searching for an entity in my CosmicMind/Graph database. 
Here is the code, which is pretty explanatory

```
//User 1
//data: 14 Febbraio 2017
//ora : 15:40
//name: Paolo

//User 2
//data: 14 Febbraio 2017
//ora : 12:40
//name: Ernesto

//User 3
//data: 13 Febbraio 2017
//ora : 16:40
//name: Paolo

/*Search Parameters*/
//dataSearch = 13 Febbraio 2017
//oraSearch = 16:40
//nameSearch = Paolo

var search = Search<Entity>(graph: graph).for(types: "Users").where(properties: (key: "data", value: dataSearch)).where(properties: (key:"ora", value: oraSearch)).where(properties: (key:"name", value: nameSearch))
    //returns [User1, User3]
```

I am expecting from the search [User3], since the search parameters coincide with that entity, but instead, search is returning [User1, User3], like if dataSearch and oraSearch parameters are being ignored, and only the last search parameter nameSearch is being used for searching.
What am i doing wrong?

Comment: What is 'Search'? is that a core-data wrapper that you are using?

Comment: exactly, as you can check from the tags, graph from cosmicmind is the wrapper

Answer (score 0):

You have too many `where statements`. They are replacing themselves with each successive statement.

this:

```
.where(properties: (key: "data", value: dataSearch)).where(properties: (key:"ora", value: oraSearch)).where(properties: (key:"name", value: nameSearch)
```

should be:

```
.where(properties: (key: "data", value: dataSearch), (key:"ora", value: oraSearch), (key:"name", value: nameSearch))
```

or shorthand:

```
.where(properties: ("data", dataSearch), ("ora", oraSearch), ("name", nameSearch))
```

That's it :)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but It always returns all the users which have data equal to dataSearch, ignoring the ora and name parameters

Comment: Can you run the Graph tests and all works well? And what version are you using?

Comment: I am using the source files from github master branch

Comment: Can you run the tests successfully ?

Comment: Do you mean the samples projects from github?

Comment: In the GitHub repo and project for Xcode, there are tests that you can run. Press the command+U and ensure that you choose a simulator to run the tests on. It cannot be generic type or an actual device. If all tests pass, then there is an issue in your code, if not, then there is an issue in Graph. ------ I ran the tests, there is one issue, that I now fixed and am pushing for release. [Graph 2.1.1](https://github.com/CosmicMind/Graph/releases/tag/2.1.1).

Comment: Could this issue be related to the problem i am having ? Searching parameters are of type Date,String and Int

Comment: No, and I published a fix. It was an API change that wasn't appropriately updated in the tests.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: I "solved" using another parameter for retrieving the records, a String type. It worked perfectly as searchingParameter, instead of Date type.Then, i did some operation on the data to isolate the correct result.

Maybe my xcode console can help you, but first i show you my code:

```
let search = Search<Entity>(graph: DataManager.shared.graph).for(types: DataManager.shared.entityType).where(properties: (key: "data", value: (DataManager.shared.datasource[0][0]["data"] as! Date)))
print("The date i am searching for->",DataManager.shared.datasource[0][0]["data"]!)
for (index,res) in search.sync().enumerated(){
    print("Result #\(index)->\(res["data"]!)")
}
print("Total results found->",search.sync().count)
print("But only 10 records meet the requirement, not 22")

The date i am searching for-> 2017-02-16 11:19:14 +0000
Result #0->2017-02-15 22:31:28 +0000
Result #1->2017-02-15 22:21:51 +0000
Result #2->2017-02-15 22:31:43 +0000
Result #3->2017-02-15 22:44:31 +0000
Result #4->2017-02-16 10:56:37 +0000
Result #5->2017-02-16 10:56:48 +0000
Result #6->2017-02-16 10:59:23 +0000
Result #7->2017-02-15 22:32:01 +0000
Result #8->2017-02-16 10:56:21 +0000
Result #9->2017-02-15 22:23:06 +0000
Result #10->2017-02-16 11:16:00 +0000
Result #11->2017-02-16 11:19:14 +0000
Result #12->2017-02-15 22:32:12 +0000
Result #13->2017-02-15 22:42:12 +0000
Result #14->2017-02-16 11:18:07 +0000
Result #15->2017-02-16 10:59:59 +0000
Result #16->2017-02-15 22:31:36 +0000
Result #17->2017-02-16 10:58:24 +0000
Result #18->2017-02-16 10:59:07 +0000
Result #19->2017-02-15 22:23:22 +0000
Result #20->2017-02-15 22:31:49 +0000
Result #21->2017-02-15 22:32:18 +0000
Total results found-> 22
But only 10 records meet the requirement, not 22
```